# City belongsThroughCountyTo Province association, how to simplify the code?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, model, associations

**Tables:**

`Province hasMany County`, `County belongsTo Province`, `County hasMany City`, `City belongsTo County`

So basically something like: `City belongsThroughCountyTo Province`

**Situation:**

In a search form I have a select drop down menu with provinces.

**The "code":**

When I list the results, I first get ids of counties that belong to the specified province, and then do a `City.county_id IN (array_of_counties_ids_here)`.

**Question:**

My question is, could I be doing it in a better way? Without first accessing the counties table. A simple three way join should do the trick, but I don't have an idea on how to implement it in Cake.

Adding a `province_id` field to the cities table isn't a solution in my case (can't alter tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid this by creating a view in SQL that directly links City to Province.

Assuming you've got:

```
tblCity
  city_id
  county_id
  name --etc
tblCounty
  county_id
  province_id
  name --whatever else
tblProvince
  province_id
  --whatever else

create or replace view CityToProvince as 
  select c.city_id, p.province_id from tblCity c
  join tblCounty co on co.county_id = c.county_id
  join tblProvince p on p.province_id = co.province_id;
```

Once that is created, you can:

```
select province_id from CityToProvince where city_id = [whatever];
```

Comment: Well, that's a good answer, and I thought about making a view, but the thing is... I only have an SELECT privilege on the database.

Comment: Ah.  That would put a damper on things.  Could you have you DBA create this view for you?  I only have read access to the production database at our company, but there are people I can pass stuff like this over to.

Comment: Creating a view seems to be the only way. I asked The Admin nicely and I got it ;] thanks